# Use X over an intermediate machine

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

EDIT: I didn't setup my `sshd_config` file correctly on the WORK machine. Even though I uncommented the line `X11Forwarding no`, I didn't realize that it said "no" instead of yes. Since the default is "no", I just assumed, without paying much attention, that it would be `X11Forwarding yes` after I uncomment it.

I have a public machine, MIDDLE. I have another machine at work: WORK that I want to be able to access from my home computer: HOME.

HOME can access MIDDLE and WORK can access MIDDLE but MIDDLE cannot access either machine directly and HOME and WORK can't access each other directly.

I have an SSH server running on WORK with X11Forwarding enabled. If I setup a reverse tunnel from WORK to MIDDLE, and then from HOME do `ssh -X MIDDLE` and then `ssh -X -p <someport> localhost`, I get `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`.

Commands I am using to setup the tunnels:

```
# On machine WORK:
user2@WORK:   $ ssh -R 33333:localhost:22 user1@MIDDLE

# On machine HOME:
user@HOME:    $ ssh -Y user1@MIDDLE
# And then on machine MIDDLE:
 user1@MIDDLE: $ ssh -Y user2@localhost -p 33333
```

Note: `user1 != user2`.

Is there some way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please show us the commands used to set up the tunnel and the output of `ssh -Yv -p <someport> localhost`.

Comment: Updated the question to show the commands used. Output of `ssh -Yv -p ... localhost` at http://sprunge.us/EZMK

Comment: @mtahmed re edit: OpenSSH follows the (imho perfect) policy of putting commented-out defaults into the config file. That way you won't be surprised when you *accidentally* uncomment something.

Comment: @peterph Makes sense but I am more used to commented out lines *not* being the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

you might try to use the "new" (actually not-so-new) cmdline flag `-Y`.
it's kind of a *better* replacement for `-X`. from the manual:

```
     -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.
             Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected 
              to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

now this doesn't reveal much (at least for chaining). but a quick test shows it works:

```
   $ ssh -Y localhost   # first connection
   $ ssh -Y localhost   # second connection on top of first connection
   $ xclock
```

(i also tested in a real network, where the *MIDDLE* machine is definitely a server without any X11, so it does work)

Comment: I setup the reverse tunnel as above and then do `ssh -Y MIDDLE` and then `ssh -Y localhost -p ...` and it doesn't work. Same error `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`.

Comment: @mtahmed i replayed your setup with the remote port forwarding (which is indeed a bit more complex than my example), and it *does* work here. are you sure that XForwarding is setup correctly on *WORK*? e.g. can you do `ssh -Y user2@WORK xclock` from an X-enabled machine that can directly reach *WORK* (in the worst case do it from *WORK* itself, but preferrably from another machine in your *worknet*)

Comment: I see what you mean. Should have tested that first. If I do `ssh -Y user2@localhost` from work, I get the same error `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`. I will try to find a way to fix that and post back here.

Comment: Sorry, I was making a very stupid mistake. I updated the question to reflect my stupidity. :p

Comment: @mtahmed do does it work now? if so, you should accept an answer to mark the question as "closed". (if you feel that none of the answers actually fits the bill, feel free to provide and accept your own answer, e.g. "the solution was to set `X11Forwarding yes` in sshd_config")

Answer (score 0):

Plain

```
ssh -Y user1@MIDDLE -p 33333
```

on HOME should do the trick. No need for `ssh -Y user2@localhost -p 33333` on MIDDLE.

Comment: but only if *MIDDLE* is not protected by a firewall that blocks `33333`

Comment: @umläute is there any mention of firewall blocking the forwarded port on that machine in the question? Usually making the pipeline shorter makes it much less prone to errors.

Comment: I was merely noting that your solution might have problems in a firewalled setup (the OP did'nt mention anywhere that there is *no* firewall protecting *MIDDLE*; however, the entire scenario is based on heavy firewalling - of *WORK* and *HOME*). I totally agree with the shortening of pipelines; I don't see however how your solution can help with the OP's original problem - they obviously were able to login to the WORK-machine so the tunneling was setup correctly.

Comment: @umläute not necessarily firewalling - pure NAT is enough (which is the most usual case in this scenario).